# SQL to Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

How do I go about writing the relational algebra for this SQL query?

```
Select patient.name, 
       patient.ward, 
       medicine.name, 
       prescription.quantity, 
       prescription.frequency
From patient, medicine, prescription
Where prescription.frequency = "3perday" 
  AND prescription.end-date="08-06-2010" 
  AND canceled = "Y"
```

Relations...

**prescription**

- prescription-ref
- patient-ref
- medicine-ref
- quantity
- frequency
- end-date
- cancelled (Y/N))

**medicine**

- medicine-ref
- name

**patient**

- Patient-ref
- name
- ward

Comment: @tike Can you edit the question to supply the columns for patient, medicine, and prescription?

Comment: martin question is edited,  is that what u mean?

Comment: If this is homework, you should at least post your best attempt, rather than just asking for the answer.

Comment: @tike - No there should be some way of joining the relations that you have not shown, I would have thought. Is this homework? If so was that the actual question?

Comment: no i am 27 year old working person i am not in college or school and if you see my past question i am asking for some individual purpose. and relational algebra of one sql query you it shouldnt be homework. :P

Comment: @ Martin yes i know there is some symbolic representation but i was not sure how to rewrite the join query thats why i asked the question as this is not comming anymore into my life this is only place i am stucked with relational algebra i dont need it anymore so i thought asking question would give some idea.

Comment: @tike - But from what you have posted there is nothing that says how a prescription is linked to a patient, or a prescription to a medicine or how a patient or medicine is uniquely identified.

Comment: @ martin .... here is the table structure.

prescription (prescritiption-ref, patient-ref, madicine-ref, quantity, frequency, end-date, cancelled (Y/N))
madicine (madincine-ref, name)
patient (Patient-ref, name, ward)

Answer (score 3):

I will just point you out the operators you should use

**Projection (π)**

π(a1,...,an): The result is defined as the set that is obtained when all tuples in R are restricted to the set {a1,...,an}.

For example π(name) on your patient table would be the same as SELECT **name** FROM patient

**Selection (σ)**

σ(*condition*): Selects all those tuples in R for which *condition* holds.

For example σ(frequency = "1perweek") on your prescription table would be the same as SELECT * FROM prescription **WHERE frequency = "1perweek"**

**Cross product(X)**

R X S: The result is the cross product between R and S.

For example patient X prescription would be SELECT * FROM **patient,prescription**

You can combine these operands to solve your exercise. Try posting your attempt if you have any issues.

**Note**: I did not include the natural join as there are no joins. The cross product should be enough for this exercise.

Answer (score 3):

An example would be something like the following.  This is only if you accidentally left out the joins between patient, medicine, and prescription.  If not, you will be looking for cross product (which seems like a bad idea in this case...) as mentioned by Lombo.  I gave example joins that may fit your tables marked as "???".  If you could include the layout of your tables that would be helpful.

I also assume that canceled comes from prescription since it is not prefixed.

Edit: If you need it in standard RA form, it's pretty easy to get from a diagram.

[alt text http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/8589/diagram1b.jpg](http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/8589/diagram1b.jpg)